# How to create an NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I thought this would be very easy but is not. I searched here in stackOverflow and didn't find an answer. I only want to create a `NSNotification` like a variable.

I already configured the listener and have a valid function. So if I send:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"name" object:nil];
```

This works with no problems. But, if I try it in the same place with:

```
NSNotification *test = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"name" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:test];
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

This error appear in XCode:

```
 -[object function]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x190d90
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[object function]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x190d90'
```

**Edit 2**

Was a bug. I don't believe I start this question. There are a very small error in @"name", they are different in my code, like `@"nname"` and `@"name"`.

Because this I learn 2 things:

- Try NEVER use `postNotification`. Only when there is no other way. This is difficult to debug and can cause error.
- Always use only one variable when have to write it a lot of time, like `#define NAME @"name"` will save a lot of time to me.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: hmmm... should be the same, I am wondering if there isn't something else going on, probably a race condition.

Comment: @Nate Thorn, ok, sorry. I have to show the error message. It's a normal "unrecognized selector", when there is no listener to the notification. @Grady Player, Hum... a race condition.. This can be a very complex problem... Maybe only use what work and don't try new thing.

Comment: Third thing to learn: (3) Post your actual code. Then we'd probably have spotted the typo right off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like the problem is not in the way you are posting the notification, but rather in the way you are listening to it. You've probably told the listening class to call a selector that doesn't exist.

Comment: You are correct. I post a notification that don't exist because the text name I send was a little different. Sorry for this small bug. There are no error sending in this 2 way.